# Split a JS string then group its values into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, split

So I've got the following string `let x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day"`. This can also be a simple `let x = "2 weeks"`.

What I'm trying to do is to split this `x` by space and then group the returned values in the following manner:

```
{
months: 4,
weeks: 3,
day: 1
}
```

I've broken down the initial variable into an array, but I'm not sure how exactly should I flip those values and return them as the said object above. What I used to split these is the following:

```
let y = x.split(/ (?=[^,]+:)/).map(s => s.split(' '));
```

The above returns the following array
`["2", "Weeks", "1", "Day"]`.

How should I tackle the flip, respectively converting the result into an object.

Comment: Consider using reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd match `\S+ \S+` (non-space characters, followed by a space, followed by more non-space characters), then map to an array of entries by splitting by a space, and finally put it into an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day";
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  x.match(/\S+ \S+/g).map(match => {
    const [val, key] = match.split(' ');
    return [key, Number(val)];
  })
);
console.log(obj);
```

More concisely, using [`.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
const x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day";
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  [...x.matchAll(/(\S+) (\S+)/g)]
    .map(([_, val, key]) => [key, Number(val)])
);
console.log(obj);
```

Another option:

```js
const x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day";
const obj = {};
for (const match of x.match(/\S+ \S+/g)) {
  const [val, key] = match.split(' ');
  obj[key] = Number(val);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for all these options!

Answer (score 3):

You could get pairs and then add the key/value pair to the object.

```js
let x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day",
    result = x
        .match(/\d+\D+/g)
        .reduce((r, s) => {
            var [v, k] = s.match(/(\d+)(\D+)/).slice(1);
            r[k.trim()] = +v;
            return r;
        }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `for` loop, you can create an object from array and then just assign this object into desired object:

```
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  let result = Object.fromEntries([[arr[++i], arr[--i]]]);
  Object.assign(obj, result);
}
```

An example:

```js
let x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day";
let arr = x.split(' ');
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  let result = Object.fromEntries([[arr[++i], arr[--i]]]);
  Object.assign(obj, result);
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below snippet. it will full fill your requirement.

```
let x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day";
let y = x.split(/([0-9]{1,}\s[A-Za-z]{1,})/);
y = y.filter(q => {return q.trim()});
let temp = {}
y.forEach(q => temp[q.split(" ")[1]] = q.split(" ")[0]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet might solve the issue and provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please consider an [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the below code:

```js
let x = "4 months 3 weeks 1 day";
let dataArray = x.split(" ")

var finalObj = {}
for(var i=0; i< dataArray.length; i++) {
 if(/^[0-9]*$/.test(dataArray[i])) {
   finalObj[dataArray[i+1]] = dataArray[i];
  }
}
console.log(finalObj)
```